# Ruby recursion's behavior

Tags: ruby, recursion

In ruby, recursion is pretty straight forward. Everything before calling the method itself works as expected. However, strange thing happen after calling the method itself.

```
def AdditivePersistence(num, t = 0)
  p "when begin, num is #{num}"
  return t if num <= 9
  t += 1
  num = num.to_s.split("").inject(0) { |sum, x| sum += x.to_i }
  p "after inject, num is #{num}"
  AdditivePersistence(num, t)
  p "-----------"
  p "t = #{t}"
end

AdditivePersistence(56)
```

The result looks like this.

```
"when begin, num is 56"
"after inject, num is 11"
"when begin, num is 11"
"after inject, num is 2"
"when begin, num is 2"
"-----------"
"t = 2"
"-----------"
"t = 1"
```

This shows the code `p '---------'` after calling the method itself gets executed after the recursion is done for however many times the recursion happened.
My question is shouldn't `p '---------'` either be not executed (just like code after return), or get executed every time the method is called?

edited:

Added `p "t = #{t}"`. This result makes me even more confused. Why does t = 2 the first time? t started from 0, and gets incremented in every recursion.

Comment: "My question is shouldn't the code either be not executed (just like code after return), or get executed every time the method is called?" What lines are you referring to exactly by "the code"?

Comment: The method was called 3 times. After third call is returned with `return` in 3rd line, the control flow passes to the point where this call occured. Hence, the line `--------` is printed out, the function returns to _where the call occured_. That said, immediately before `p '-------'`. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in ruby, you shouldn't use camel case, it would be better to rename the method to  `additive_persistence`.

So you bother about

```
"-----------"
"-----------"
```

this output? It is normal behavior. The pointer is being returned to previous `AdditivePersistence(num, t)` call and execution continues to `p "-----------"`

Answer (score 1):

The function is called a total of three times.  The last call of the function results in an early return, but the first two calls run all the way to the end and print dashes before they return.  This is normal, and if you just think a little bit more about how your program works you should see there is no problem.

I indented the lines of output from your program to indicate how deep the call stack is when the output was produced:

```
"when begin, num is 56"
"after inject, num is 11"
    "when begin, num is 11"
    "after inject, num is 2"
        "when begin, num is 2"
    "-----------"
"-----------"
```

Comment: Thanks for the illustration. But if the first two calls run all the way to the end, shouldn't it run the first "--------" be displayed before the second "when begin, ..."?

Comment: No, the statments inside a method are executed in order from top to bottom, so the first call only prints dashes at the very end.

Comment: You just have to get it into your head that whenever you call a method, Ruby will execute all the lines of that method in order and then return to where you were.  There is nothing special or magical about recursion.  The first "t" value to be printed is 2 because the third call doesn't print its t and the 2nd call (where t=2) must execute completely before returning to the first.  There literally is no other logical way for the program to behave.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course program flow returns to where it should, and continues in the calling method. Recursive method invocation is just like any other method invocation. The flow of execution temporarily leaves the method and returns to the next statement. This is the same for every language. When a method calls itself, that doesn't behave any differently than when a method calls another method.

Consider:

```
def method_1
  puts "a"
  method_2
  puts "b"
end

def method_2

end
```

Do you think this program should not print `"b"` just because it invokes `method_2` and flow of control temporarily leaves `method_1`? No, obviously not. When `method_2` finishes, program flow returns to `method_1` and the next statement (`puts "b"`) executes.

Perhaps you're expecting some kind of loop behavior, where the recusrive call jumps to the top, but that's not at all what happens:

```
def AdditivePersistence(num, t = 0)
  while true
    p "when begin, num is #{num}"
    break if num <= 9
    t += 1
    num = num.to_s.split("").inject(0) { |sum, x| sum += x.to_i }
    p "after inject, num is #{num}"
    next
    # Flow will never reach this point
    p "-----------"
  end
  t
end

AdditivePersistence(56)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The example you gave is very straight forward. But, why would the line '"------"' even get called? Since it temporarily leave the method and jump to another one (in this case itself), and it stops at the line 'return'.

Comment: @EdmundLee Because every call of the function runs the entire function. When the inner invocation returns, the stack "unwinds" and continues where it left off in the previous invocation of the function. This is the same in all languages. I suggest you read up on recursive functions, you're misunderstanding how they work.

Comment: Thanks. I am still not understanding very well yet. But I will do some readings in this topic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right keyword for searching. Found the answer!

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I found my answer. Thanks everyone for helping.
I found the answer from this short video that explains how recursive function works in C++, which I believe is a similar process. This is for future reference for anyone looking for this question (turned out searching for "recursive function" instead of being specific to ruby will lead me to lots of answer).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0bb7UYy0pY

Because of how the recursive call stack works, it will start unwinding after the call stack reaches the base case. That's why in my code, `p "---------"` is called twice, and why `t = 2` first, then `t = 1` in the output.

Correct me if I am not understanding this correctly.